# How to get the language tags of a repository in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

How do i get the github repository language tags. Is there any api to get those tags. i refereed there [developer docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/) but no solution can anybody help on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a primary or a list of languages from github's URL using github API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371596/how-to-get-a-primary-or-a-list-of-languages-from-githubs-url-using-github-api)

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit hidden in the examples, but:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<reponame>/languages
```

Gives a list of languages used, like this:

```
{
    "Java": 123721,
    "CSS": 1334
}
```

You get the URL from a repository get as explained here: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get - it is the `"languages_url"`, but unfortunately it returns an empty object for the [hello world example](https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/languages) that is used in the documentation. If you try it for an [actual repository](https://api.github.com/repos/tapioaali/GoogleMapsVaadin7/languages), it works.