# How to get a primary or a list of languages from github's URL using github API?

Tags: api, github, github-api

I have an url to github repo, for instance: `https://github.com/dotnet/corefx`

Is there any possible approach in github's API to get "C#" as a primary language of the repository?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [List languages Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages) that will give you all language used in this repo with the number of bytes of code written in that language :

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/dotnet/corefx/languages
```

that will give you :

```json
{
  "C#": 131055040,
  "C": 1078381,
  "Visual Basic": 829607,
  "C++": 622926,
  "XSLT": 462336,
  "OpenEdge ABL": 139178,
  "Shell": 70286,
  "CMake": 60136,
  "PowerShell": 51624,
  "DIGITAL Command Language": 26402,
  "Groovy": 25726,
  "Batchfile": 21796,
  "Objective-C": 9455,
  "Makefile": 9085,
  "Roff": 4236,
  "Perl": 3895,
  "ASP": 1687,
  "Python": 1535,
  "1C Enterprise": 903,
  "HTML": 653
}
```

With bash you can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) to parse and select the field with the max bytes value :

```bash
language=`curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/dotnet/corefx/languages | jq 'to_entries | max_by(.value) | .key'`
echo "$language"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Update for 2023

you can find the docs for the list of languages [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-repository-languages)

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode/languages
```

and you can also find the most used language in the repo if you do a normal repo request under the `language` property

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode
```