# How to get a github usesr top laguages used using a github api

Tags: github, github-api

is there and way to get a users most used languages just like github gives us
like this:
https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=rjoydip
using GitHub API

Answer (score 0):

Apprently not, if I interpret correctly the [`anuraghazra/github-readme-stats/src/fetchers/top-languages-fetcher.js#fetchTopLanguages()`](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats/blob/02ebd3243b4dc1aba224c7c75c23ebd3e4867ed2/src/fetchers/top-languages-fetcher.js#L37-L73) function used to get those stats.

It has to iterate on all repositories, and [get languages from each one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42372943/6309).